# Replace last string in IP-address accornding to specific condition in PL/SQL

Tags: mysql, plsql, ip-address, regexp-replace

I've got table with fields and values:

```
 ENTADDR (VARCHAR2)     ENTIFINDEX (VARCHAR2)
18.17.16.2                1
18.17.16.53               2
18.17.16.1                3
18.17.16.54               4
```

I have to join 1st and 3rd record knowing 1st ENTADDR.
So how can I get  18.17.16.1  from 18.17.16.2? (last char -1). Similarly I have to join 2nd and 4th record knowing 2nd ENTADDR (18.17.16.54 from 18.17.16.53, i.e last char +1)

So I need "select" like:

Select 
ENTIFINDEX from table1 
where '*some transformation of ENTADDR (changing last char)* '= ENTADDR

Thanks in advice!!

Comment: What would be your expected output ? Provide some more information.

Comment: what do you mean by joining? Please provide the sample output required from the data you have mentioned in table

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking at

```
SQL> select concat (substr('18.17.16.2',1,9),substr ('18.17.16.2',-1)-1 ) as "concat val" from dual;

concat val
----------
18.17.16.1
```

Answer (score 0):

select concat(left(ENTADDR,locate('.',ENTADDR,locate('.',ENTADDR,locate('.',ENTADDR)+1)+1)),right(ENTADDR,length(ENTADDR)-locate('.',ENTADDR,locate('.',ENTADDR,locate('.',ENTADDR)+1)+1))-ENTIFINDEX) as ipminusone from table

That searches for first second and third '.' and then subtracts the value of ENTIFINDEX from the last portion of the IP

You could also do this with a stored procedure if you're planning on doing this fairly often.